# how to convert this quick sort into descending order?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program in C++ but I'm now stuck in this code . I want to convert this code form ascending to deserting order .

I also search it on google but didn't get any good result  from which i can be able to change this code into descending order .

I'll be very much thank full if you edit it ...

I also tried it to change the these "<" and ">" but no use

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
 
void swap(int* a, int* b)  
{  
    int t = *a;  
    *a = *b;  
    *b = t;  
}  
  
int partition (int arr[], int low, int high)  
{  
    int pivot = arr[high]; 
    int i = (low - 1);  
  
    for (int j = low; j <= high - 1; j++)  
    {   
        if (arr[j] < pivot)  
        {  
            i++;  
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);  
        }  
    }  
    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]);  
    return (i + 1);  
}  
  
void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high)  
{  
    if (low < high)  
    {  
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high);  
        quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1);  
        quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high);  
    }  
}  
   
//   


int partition(int userinput[], int p, int r)
{
    int pivot = userinput[r];
    
    while (p < r)
    {
        while (userinput[p] < pivot)
        {
            p++;
        }
        while (userinput[r] > pivot)
        {
            r--;
        }
        if (userinput[p] == userinput[r])
        {
            p++;
        }
        else if (p < r)
        {
            int tmp = userinput[p];
            userinput[p] = userinput[r];
            
            userinput[r] = tmp;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
void quickSort(int * userinput, int p, int r)
{
    if (p < r)
    {
        int j = partition(userinput, p, r);
        
        quickSort(userinput, p, j - 1);
        quickSort(userinput, j + 1, r);
    }
}

main(){
    int size,option;
    cout<<"   ***SORTING PROGRAM*** \n";
    
    cout<<"Enter the Size of the ARRAY: ";
    cin>>size; 
    
    int arr[size];
    
    cout<<"\nEnter Element of the ARRAY: ";
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    
    cout<<"\n In what order you want the Element to be sorted \n\n";
    cout<<"press 1 for ASCENDING order \n";
    cout<<"press 2 For DESCENDING order \n";
    cin>>option;
    
    quickSort(arr,0,size-1);//,option
    
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
}#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
 
void swap(int* a, int* b)  
{  
    int t = *a;  
    *a = *b;  
    *b = t;  
}  
  
int partition (int arr[], int low, int high)  
{  
    int pivot = arr[high]; 
    int i = (low - 1);  
  
    for (int j = low; j <= high - 1; j++)  
    {   
        if (arr[j] < pivot)  
        {  
            i++;  
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);  
        }  
    }  
    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]);  
    return (i + 1);  
}  
  
void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high)  
{  
    if (low < high)  
    {  
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high);  
        quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1);  
        quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high);  
    }  
}  
   
//   

main(){
    int size,option;
    cout<<"   ***SORTING PROGRAM*** \n";
    
    cout<<"Enter the Size of the ARRAY: ";
    cin>>size; 
    
    int arr[size];
    
    cout<<"\nEnter Element of the ARRAY: ";
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    
    cout<<"\n In what order you want the Element to be sorted \n\n";
    cout<<"press 1 for ASCENDING order \n";
    cout<<"press 2 For DESCENDING order \n";
    cin>>option;
    
    quickSort(arr,0,size-1);//,option
    
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: First you need to know how [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Implementation_issues) works. Then it should be easy. Tip: look at partition.

Comment: `int arr[size];` -- This is not valid C++, as arrays in C++ require the number of items to be denoted by a compile-time value, not a runtime variable.  First, you should be using a regular array with data that does not work -- there is no need for `cin` statements:  `int arr[] = {1, 5, 4, 2 17, 9};` and try to get that to work first.

Comment: Instead of using operators <, >, <=, >=, directly, use a comparator class (or functions) that perform these comparisons. Then you can switch from ascending to descending by swapping the comparator that has all the operations reversed.